# Write ogrinfo result to text file

Tags: gdal, ogr, text

I have obtained a desired value from a dataset using: 
`ogrinfo input.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT SUM(field) from input`

The ogrinfo command prints the desired value via the command line when I run this in a python script. I need to write out this result to a .txt or .csv file as my intention is to display it in a barplot, ideally using plotly.

Other relevant info: 
Windows 7, Python 3.3
GDAL 1.11

Comment: Are you running that command in a shell or from python with `subprocess` or the like?

Comment: I'm running the command from python 3.4 with the os.system() call

Comment: Is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7152903/1504487) what you want?

Comment: I don't think that would work, as the desired output is not printed to the command line via a `print()` command. It is printed as the result of the `ogrinfo` command

Comment: `ogrinfo` prints the result to `stdout`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might depend on your operating system which you did not mention. Usually "command > filename" works to print the output into a file instead of the terminal.

Note that this only captures the result, not any debug information, if you want to pipe debug information to a file you'll need to specify the location in a config setting like:

```
ogrinfo --debug on --config CPL_LOG C:/LOGS/your-debug.log -ro ...
```

Comment: Windows 7, Python 3.3, GDAL 1.11

Comment: This works! Simply adding ` > out.txt` to the end of my command did the trick

Comment: Sweet! Be aware that you can also use GDAL directly via Python without the need to call the "external tools": https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/